# How to find Back Button Using Android?

Tags: android

How can I go to the previous page from Current Page?

For Instance:

First User Clicks Music Page, it invokes a WebView which displays the Music URL & then the User Clicks Back button, at that time previous page(i.e. Music Page) must be displayed.

Comment: This is handled automatically by the platform...

Comment: is music page again a WebView? showing some code might be good.

Comment: No the Music Page is not a Web View

Comment: which means on click, android browser is opening up. Then it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Hai frnd, I will tell the Problem clearly ,Music Page is a List view,In that  Asynchronous Task to show progress bar to parse Music page list Content, When the User clicks the List row, then url is parssed & web view is invoked. Now if the User Clicks Back Button either in the Device or in UI, it should go to the previous page but it moves the previous page without listing the content of the previous page. 
Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing in the default functionality. If you put the WebView into a new activity, then you can call `startActivity` from the "main page" activity to start the "music page" activity. When the user pushes the back button, it will automatically return to the main page.